# Office 365 Azure AD: How get members of AD Groups

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I use the graph API to get a group in Azure AD.
After getting the group by displayname I'd like to get the members of this group.
But in the response I dont see any members, I only see the same group for which I made the query.
What am I doing wrong?

**Request**:

> https://graph.windows.net/(TenantID)/groups/(GroupID)/members?api-version=2013-11-08

**Response**:

```js
{
  odata.metadata: "https://graph.windows.net/(TenantID)/$metadata#directoryObjects"
  value: [1]
  0: {
      odata.type: "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ActiveDirectory.Group"
      objectType: "Group"
      objectId: "GroupID edited by me"
      description: "Admin permission for all Sitecollections with Category PRJ"
      dirSyncEnabled: true
      displayName: "XXX_PRJ_A_SP"
      lastDirSyncTime: "2015-06-11T08:00:19Z"
      mail: null
      mailNickname: "XXX_PRJ_A_SP"
      mailEnabled: false
      provisioningErrors: [0]
      proxyAddresses: [0]
      securityEnabled: true
    } -
    -
}
```

How can I get the members of this group?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using a newer Graph API version like 1.5?

I tested this query using the Graph Explorer, and I was able to get back the members of a group. Please take a look here:
https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/Home/Index/DemoCompany?UrlRequest=GET&text=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fgraphdir1.onmicrosoft.com%2Fgroups%2F07106f0b-6c43-4412-9795-c5571fbc8ff1%2Fmembers

The query is:
https://graph.windows.net/graphdir1.onmicrosoft.com/groups/07106f0b-6c43-4412-9795-c5571fbc8ff1/members

Hopefully this helps you resolve whatever issues you might be running into.

Thanks,
Shawn Tabrizi

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this don't work either....I think the problem is that this group is created from "local Active Directory" and includes an AD group. When I open the Adminpage of windows Azure, I only see a string with the Name "XXX_PRJ_A_SP" when I expand the group. Can this be the reason?